# How to calculate % increase using aggregate functions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

In Python, I have a pandas DataFrame similar to the following:

```
id      city         start_date     end_date       quantity
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  |   NLR    |  2017-08-21    |  2017-08-27      9         |
2  |   GDR    |  2018-08-23    |  2018-08-23      9         |
3  |   HYD    |  2018-08-23    |  2018-08-23      21        |
4  |   NLR    |  2019-09-25    |  2019-09-25      18        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have to group by city, and then calculate the % increase in the current year compared to previous years.
(for caluculating the % increase ,increase /originalNumber*100.)

For example the city NLR has 2 rows, so % increase is double in the year 2019-09-25, compared to the year 2017-08-21.

I have tried to below :

```
print (g1.groupby( g1['city']).sum())
```

but not understood, how to get max() value of quantity column when order by city. there may be n number of years for a city every time i need to find the max() and sum() then calculate %. can someone help or guide me how to do?

Answer (score 2):

`g1.groupby(['city'])['quantity'].pct_change()` should do it.

Comment: where the year is considered?